# PHP - strtotime(+ month) in a foreach. February problems

Tags: php, foreach, strtotime

I have a foreach that adds months. But I'm in trouble when the month is February, because when my variable `$day` is `30`, it does not work well.

```
$contador = 0;
foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
    try {
        $exp = date('Y-m-' . $day . ' H:i:s', strtotime("+" . $contador . " month"));
        $contador++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "does not work well" -- particularly in relation to what you expect to happen.

Comment: That's why you shouldn't add months directly to dates at the end of a  month.... if it's supposed to be the last day of the month, then use first day of the month to do your adding months, and then format to display the last day.... otherwise, find out what the your business rule should be for months with fewer than 31 days (because there's quite a lot of those in every year)

Comment: Note that `strtotime()` takes an amazing variety of input, like `last day of this month` and `first day of next month`.

Comment: Does not work well because when its February, goes to march. I want that when month == 02, goes to last day of month, but I dont know how do this in a foreach.